# PHPExcel set bottom border

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to have a range with a bottom border. I got this code:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle('A4:G4')
            ->getBorders()
            ->getBottom()
            ->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);
```

But I do not know why this will make a left border.
What do I wrong.